# include javascript in dynamically added jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am creating a j2ee application, I have header.jsp, footer.jsp and one result.jsp which is the main page where I am doing some calculations and showing results.
I am using ajax to include content of a page calculate.jsp in a div area in result.jsp page.
calculate.jsp page is using some java script functions from a js library, the java script library if i include in header.jsp they are not picked up by calculate.jsp. It throws error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

If I include javascript library in calculate.jsp it works fine. But I want to use function of js library in other pages also. Is there a way to include js lib in header.jsp page and make it work?

Edit:

I am ploting graphs in calculate.jsp this is the code :

```
<script>
 nv.addGraph(function() {
      var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                    .width(750).height(370)
                    .margin({left: 100})  //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
                    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
                    .transitionDuration(350)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
                    .showLegend(true)       //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
                    .showYAxis(true)        //Show the y-axis
                    .showXAxis(true)        //Show the x-axis
      ;      

      formatter = function(i){
          return dateArrBC[i];
      };

      chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings
          .axisLabel('Date')
           .tickFormat(formatter); 

      chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
          .axisLabel('')
          .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

      d3.select('#chart-area svg')    //Select the <svg> element you want to render the chart in.   
          .datum(data)         //Populate the <svg> element with chart data...
          .call(chart);          //Finally, render the chart!

      nv.utils.windowResize(function() { chart.update(); });
      return chart;
    });
</script>
```

Its using addGraph function which if included in same page(calculate.jsp) works but if I include library in header.jsp it throws function not found.
Using spring framework, so ajax calls a controller function which returns calculate.body

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: how are you loading the page? Maybe you're only loading its contents but not its scripts [more info here](https://api.jquery.com/load/) at Script Execution

Comment: If you're using `<jsp:include.../>` you shouldn't have this issue unless your various JSP files are in different directories and your javascript is referenced by a path relative to one that doesn't work from the location of the other.

Comment: i added my js code, I am using ajax to include the content of another page its included in a div.

Answer (score 0):

No i don't think so  as `calculate.jsp` is dynamically generated and javascript binding  with DOM elements happens at the time of page loading.

So if your are trying to use any javascript function from any js file in `calculate.jsp` you should import that js file in `calculate.jsp`